# How to make the columns fill a data grid view completely

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 columns in my data grid view. But these 2 columns occupy only a portion of the view. How do i make both columns fill the view completely such first columns takes 50% space and second column takes the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
this.MyColumn1.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.MyColumn2.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Then play with property `this.MyColumn2.FillWeight` for your purpose...

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio in the properties window, when you select the dataGridView go to the property **AutoSizeColumnsMode** and select the option **Fill**.
All the columns will fit all the place of the dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column width to fill e.g.

```
oColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

If you do this for all columns they will equally fill the grid (with or without the scrollbars). If you only sent if for 1 column that column will fill the remaining space leftover after all columns have been sized